# Interface used to make it more testable

Tags: java, unit-testing

I was looking at android source code and i found this code.

```
/**
 * Interface used in {@link #createUniqueFile} instead of {@link File#createNewFile()} to make
 * it testable.
 */
/* package */ interface NewFileCreator {
    public static final NewFileCreator DEFAULT = new NewFileCreator() {
                @Override public boolean createNewFile(File f) throws IOException {
                    return f.createNewFile();
                }
    };
    public boolean createNewFile(File f) throws IOException ;
}
```

How is it more testable? And can anybody redirect me to the place where i can see more examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is so that in your tests you can substitute the NewFileCreator with a different implementation wherever it's being used - one that just saves the data in memory for example.

This means you can test the logic of whatever's using this without worrying about making sure a real filesystem exists and that it's in a suitable state.

Comment: More examples of the pattern?  Or different implementations of this interface?

Comment: more example of this pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familar with the Android codebase, but the principle is to enable Dependency Injection - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 1):

I think the statement "to make it testable" refers to the method `createUniqueFile` that seems to use an instance of `NewFileCreator`. That method is supposed to be better testable in isolation as it is easier to mock a `NewFileCreator` than it is to mock a `File` from standard Java API. Also one can provide different implementations of the `NewFileCreator` for testing that do not mess up the file system.